# Performance issue in IEnumerable type when querying large amount of data with LINQ

Tags: linq, ienumerable, query-performance

I'm using LINQ to execute a query on a List type variable with a large amount of data (over a million). For performance purposes I'm using IEnumerable to store the results but when I try to access it there is a slight delay.

Specifically I want to see if the query produced any results, but when I use the .Count() or .Any() functions the performance drops.

I read that for IEnumerable types the execution of the query happens at the time of need, hence the delay. Is there a way to see if the IEnumerable has elements inside it without having that much delay?

This is what I'm trying to run.

```
IEnumerable<Entity> matchingEntities = entities.Where(e => e.Names.Any(n => myEntity.Names.Any(entityName => entityName.CompareNameObjects(n))));
```

and here are my classes

```
public class Entity
{
   public string EntityIdentifier { get; set; }
   public List<Name> Names { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string NameType { get; set; }

    public bool CompareNameObjects(Name name2)
    {
        return FullName == name2.FullName &&
               NameType == name2.NameType;
    }
}
```

*entities* is a list of all my objects and I want to check if *myEntity* has any Names identical with another entity in the set.

EDITED:

The data structure is similar to the 2 classes (Entity and Name). The entities are created by selecting all the entities, along with their names, from the database in XML format and then I convert the XML to a List as such:

```
List<Entity> entities = new List<Entity>();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCS"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllEntities", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    string entitiesXml = "";
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            entitiesXml += rdr["XmlString"].ToString();
        }
    }

    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(entitiesXml))
        entities = (Entity)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

    conn.Close();
}

GetAllEntities (Stored Procedure):
declare @xmlString nvarchar(max) =(
    select  e.EntityIdentifier,
        (
            select  n.[Full Name]  as 'FullName', 
                    n.[Name Type]  as 'NameType'
            from tblNames n
            where e.EntityID=n.[Entity_ID]
            for xml path('Name'), type
        )
    from tblEntities e 
    order by e.EntityID
    for xml path('Entity')
) 
select @xmlString as XmlString
```

Comment: Show us where "entities" is from. If you are using EF, to get the best performance, you should avoid using Enumerable as much as possible

Comment: _Entities_ comes from a query on SQL Server. To get all the entities I have a small delay but I don't mind that.

Comment: You cannot use CompareNameObjects in EF because it forces your code to run on RAM, not in SQL Server which is very slow. Please rephrase your condition to  filter data directly. "Any" can be translated to SQL scripts, so no problem for it. 
Ex: entities.Where(e => e.Names.Any(n => myEntity.Names.Any(entityName => entityName.FullName  == n.FullName  && entityName.NameType  == n.NameType)));

Comment: Tried this but i get the same result

Comment: I cannot tell you more if I don't know the table structures and what entities is

Comment: I have edited my original post with more information

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should avoid getting all data from your database then filter it with C# code. It consumes a lot of effort.

However, for quick solution, you can improve performance by preparing your conditions in a Dictionary form firstly.

```
 // Let's say you have myEntity here
 var myEntity = new Entity();
 var entities = new List<Entity>();

 // You should prepare the list of name that you wanna to find before you do it so that you don't have to make it repeatedly for every iteration
 var names = myEntity.Names.Select(p=> p.FullName + p.NameType ).ToDictionary(p=>p, p=>p);

 IEnumerable<Entity> matchingEntities = entities.Where(e => e.Names.Any(n => names.ContainsKey(n.FullName + n.NameType)));
```

This is just an example that may give you more idea. You can improve much more. I hope it can help you